# Connecting to Dropbox via a proxy

Tags: proxy, dropbox

My computer can't connect to Dropbox on its own. Most of the ports in the network are closed.

Firefox accesses the Internet through an automatic proxy configuration file URL.

In Dropbox's proxy settings, there's however no field for an automatic proxy configuration file URL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Copy the URL of the proxy configuration file (.PAC file) and go to the URL with Firefox.

Firefox will either:

- immediately open the file in the browser or
- ask with which program to open it. Open the file with a text editor of your liking.

In the PAC file, search for "PROXY". Next to it, you should find the address of the proxy server used in your company. You can use that information `proxyserver:port` in the Dropbox proxy settings.

If you have several proxy servers defined in the PAC file, check them all until you find the right one that let Dropbox access the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, DropBox does have an automatic proxy setting. Just update yours to version 0.7.110 or later (you may even try the 0.8.1 beta if you're brave!)

[image: Proxy settings in DropBox]

Comment: It has but it isn't smart enough to autodetect in this network.

Comment: Have you reported a bug to the Dropbox team? It's nice to have a workaround, but even nicer to have a fix in the next version :)